# Which part of the hard disk does the BIOS backup get stored?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, boot, bios

I have a Gigabyte 880GM-USB3 motherboard, purchased around 2015. In all these years there has been no BIOS update. I don't remember switching on any setting that would perform an auto-update of the BIOS either. Few days back I used Ubuntu's updater to update the software in Ubuntu. Yesterday, when I started the computer, I saw this:

[image]

Since a computer-savvy cousin had been to my room sometime back, I took some caution considering the "evil maid attack", and didn't update the BIOS. Also because [Q-Flash recommends](https://www.gigabyte.com/MicroSite/121/tech_qflash.htm) not updating. However, I selected the option to save BIOS to Drive.
On doing this, it prompted me for a name to give the saved file, and I named it "biosSometh".

On restarting the computer, I searched the filesystem for this file, but couldn't find it. I don't have Windows installed. It's only Ubuntu.

**May I know where such a file typically gets saved?** I need to wipe the disk and re-install the OS, so it'd be nice to retain a copy of this saved BIOS file.

Comment: You have looked on the flash drive? Why don’t you just repeat your actions and save another copy?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Ramhound: What flash drive? I have only one hard disk. I didn't use any extra pen drive during this process. What steps do I repeat? I just started my computer and this screen showed up. It has not showed up ever since. Even if I repeat the process, I still don't know where on the disk to find the saved file.

Comment: You apply a firmware update by using a removable flash drive formatted properly.  I took the “flash type” as a flash drive, and you specifically mentioned, your cousins drive. Download Q-Flash and repeat the process

Comment: There was no option to specify a directory to save the file to. It didn't even show me which directory it was going to be saved to. It only allowed me to enter a filename of my choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **May I know where such a file typically gets saved?**

Typically it would be to the root of the drive, which must be a FAT32/16/12 formatted filesystem according to the [User Guide](https://www.gigabyte.com/FileUpload/Global/MicroSite/121/flashbios_qflash.pdf) linked on their page:

> `Q-Flash only supports USB flash drive or hard drives using FAT32/16/12 file system.`

If there was no FAT formatted drive attached, it wasn't saved anywhere.

**EDIT:** if the computer has an EFI partition (FAT32), it is probably saved there.

Comment: Yes, there is a Fat32 partition as `sda1`, but how do I verify if the file is there? `ls` does not work. I'm trying to find a way to copy that file and keep it as a backup.

Comment: @JohnDavid `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt` then `sudo find /mnt -type f -name biosSometh` will locate the file (if it exists) and return the full path to it. If the location returned by `find` was `/mnt/biosSometh` then `sudo cp /mnt/biosSometh ~/` will copy the file to your home directory. Note that the file copy will also be owned by `root`. Finally, do `sudo umount /dev/sda1` to unmount the EFI partition.